# pandas dataframe slower to read from parquet than from pickle file

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pickle, parquet

According to this benchmark at https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d
which uses categorical column as strings, and numerical columns as floats, 
Pandas dataframes should read faster when loaded from a parquet file than from a pickle file.

I happen to consistently see the opposite with the following use case, where I have only 1 column of strings with a fixed number of characters where all characters can vary from one row to the next, here's an example of these strings:

> ./2010/10/12/2010-10-12T02:38:47.09Z_blah0.fixedword1.fixedword2

where all the characters except "fixedword1" and "fixedword2" change from one row to the next (these varying characteres are dates and times ranging from year 2010 to year 2018 at about a 1 second increment (increment not constant).

I have about **130 million rows** in this dataframe.

The dataframe is constructed out of csv file that contain these strings:

```
df = pd.read_csv(flist, names=['path_str'], dtype=object)
```

and saved to pickle and parquet files as:

```
parquet_f = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'df.parquet')
df.to_parquet(parquet_f, engine='pyarrow', compression=None)

pickle_f = os.path.join(parent_dir, 'df.pkl')
df.to_pickle(pickle_f)
```

How come I consistently get the opposite with`pickle` file being read about 3 times faster than `parquet` with 130 million rows with these kinds of strings? 
I tried the benchmark linked above by setting the same number of rows and `parquet` was still consistently faster.

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow is not the best venue for this discussion. The dataset you described is not an ideal application for Parquet because the compression strategies that it uses for analytics datasets (with lots of repeated strings, etc.) don't help very much. I'd be glad to discuss more on dev@parquet.apache.org

Comment: I get the same behavior as you. to_pickle() is ~3x faster than to_parquet.

Comment: But it has its dark side as well- Pickle due to its speed (80-100 GB per second read speeds on a RAID 5 with SSDs) can easily destabilize other users server apps in a shared system (e.g. on a k8s node). The impact on the k8s cluster of such fast memory allocation is apparently the same as a complete memory exhaustion.